# How do I load waiting timer onclick on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have somewhat achieved what I wanted to (can be seen in preview) but it still has some issues. For example, when I click on "Request code again" hyperlink there's a sudden pause before it starts a timer, how to remove that sudden pause?. Secondly, how to remove hyperlink on the timer?

Lastly, how do I change the timer in seconds (60, 59, 58, ..) to minutes and seconds like (02:00, 01:59, 01:58, ...) with a text added. For example, "Request another code in 02:00", "Request another code in 01:59", "Request another code in 01:58", and so on.

I hope to see someone helping me.

```js
var display_timer_interval;
var timer_output_initial = 5
var timer_output = timer_output_initial;
var initial_text = "";
$("#timer_link").on("click", function() {
  var clicked_element = $(this);
  initial_text = clicked_element.html();
  display_timer_interval = setInterval(function() {
    display_time(clicked_element);
  }, 1000);
});

function display_time(element) {
  timer_output = timer_output - 1;
  if (timer_output === 0) {
    clearInterval(display_timer_interval);
    timer_output = timer_output_initial;
    element.html(initial_text);
  } else {
    $(element).html(timer_output);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(1);" id="timer_link">Request code again</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'sudden pause' happens because the callback function of setinterval doesn't get fired immediately. It first will be called if a second has passed.

You can overcome this by calling the callback itself once.

To format a number to show 2 digits you have to check if it's smaller than 10 and if it is, prepend a zero.

```js
var display_timer_interval;
var timer_output_initial = 5
var timer_output = timer_output_initial;
var initial_text = "";
$("#timer_link").on("click", function() {
  var clicked_element = $(this);
  initial_text = clicked_element.html();
  display_time(clicked_element);
  display_timer_interval = setInterval(function() {
    display_time(clicked_element);
  }, 1000);
});

function display_time(element) {
  timer_output = timer_output - 1;
  if (timer_output === 0) {
    clearInterval(display_timer_interval);
    timer_output = timer_output_initial;
    element.html(initial_text);
  } else {
    var minutes = Math.floor(timer_output / 60);
    var seconds = timer_output - minutes * 60
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    $(element).html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(1);" id="timer_link">Request code again</a>
```

Comment: To add to this answer, for removing the hyperlink from the countdown, it is best that you have a `p` element for the countdown itself. Otherwise, you can use jQuery's `css()` to set `text-decoration` to `none`.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to have a p element, please?

Comment: you can use button instead anchor - <button id="timer_link">Request code again</button>

Comment: @BillNathan use jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` to hide the `a` and display the `p`. The `p` element can be `<p id="countDownTimerDisplay" style="display: none;"></p>` and you can set its `text()` to the countdown text instead of the `a`'s. You're not changing `html` so use `text()` instead. to hide `a` and show `p` use `$('#timer_link').hide(); $('#countDownTimerDisplay').show();`. Then do the opposite when done. You can use `fadeIn()/fadeOut()` too.